# Like button not displaying thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails

My blog is [here](http://makfilmoteka.blogspot.com/). I had a few issues with the like button, most of which have been fixed, except now I have a problem with the Facebook like button not displaying thumbnails whenever the post is liked. It only displays the name of post ex.:

```
Filip Stojchevski likes a link.

Flypaper (2011) | Филмотека 

[NO THUMBNAIL]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs Open Graph meta data on your site. So you need to edit your template to include the data for Facebook. Unfortunately the Dynamic Views theme does not allow HTML edits.